# Converting from std::string to NSString

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

How can I convert from std::string to NSString in this case?

```
void Piles::imagePlacer(Card card, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    string cardType = card.toString();

    UIImageView *cardImg = [[UIImageView alloc]
                 initWithImage:cardType];
    cardImg.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, 126, 190);
    [self.view addSubview:cardImg];
}
```

I want to use a string as the name of the image (assuming I have a list of UIImages somewhere with names that correspond to all possible strings stored in cardType)?

Answer (score 13):

Just go through a C string:

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:cardType.c_str()]`

or using the new syntax:

`@(cardType.c_str())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for this :

```
string str_simple = "HELLO WORLD";

//string to NSString

NSString *stringinObjC = [NSString stringWithCString:str_simple.c_str()
                            encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];


NSLog(stringinObjC);
```